# Solving for an unknown function in a definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following equation which I want to solve for $f$ but have no idea where to start from.
$$\int_0^{2r}f^2(x)dx=\frac{2V}{\pi}$$
Any ideas on how I would go about to solve this equation?

Comment: Differentiate with respect to $r$ to obtain a differential equation (noting that presumably the volume $V$ depends on the presumably radius $r$)

Comment: Obviously there is not a unique function to give that integral, so the problem is ill posed.

Comment: Can we assume that $V=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$? That is, can we assume the volume here is that of a sphere?

Comment: Ok, I understand that I haven't formulated the question correctly. First of all, the radius and volume are constants. Also, the function $f$ describes an ellipse with the radius actually standing for the vertex of the ellipse.     
p.s. I didn't know exactly how to formulate the question and perhaps my whole approach to it is wrong. It stems from a question I have been asked by a friend about whether I could approximate the depth of an object which is roughly the shape of half a spheroid given its volume and the circumference of its cross section taken at the horizontal symmetry axis.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem